# Run .NET programs on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: .net, amazon-linux

How can I run a .NET program on an Amazon Linux AMI, either by installing Mono or .NET Core? Or is the runtime already installed?

I tried `yum -y install mono` but got `No package mono available`, and `yum -y install mono-complete` doesn't work either.

I couldn't find any way to install .NET core either - there are no packages listed when I run `yum search dotnet` (or `yum search mono` for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install .NET Core by following this tutorial - [Deploy ASP.NET Core Application On EC2 Amazon Linux Instance](https://gooroo.io/GoorooThink/Article/17422/Deploy-ASPNET-Core-Application-On-EC2-Amazon-Linux-Instance/29415).

I needed to run these commands:

```
sudo su -
yum install -y libunwind libicu
curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=835019
mkdir -p /opt/dotnet && sudo tar zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet
ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

After that I could start my application by running `dotnet MyApplication.exe`.