# Install .NET Core in Amazon Linux 2 using yum

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-ami

I cannot find a straightforward way of installing dotnet 2.2 on a AWS Linux 2 AMI.

There was some announcements that there was pre-built AMI's with it installed, but the ones I see, also have different versions of MSSQL Server.

Isn't there a way to install dotnet core 2.2 using yum or getting an AMI without SQL Server?

I found [Run .NET programs on Amazon Linux AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853821/run-net-programs-on-amazon-linux-ami) but I wonder if it is still valid, and if there is not an easier way.

Comment: Use the dropdown to select the relevant distro 
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/rhel/runtime-current

Comment: I already tried, it does not work with RH instructions (Amazon Linux is based on RH). There is not subscription-manager, and it is not available in yum. The dotnet package isn't available in yum.

Comment: Have you tried the following:               sudo yum update
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-2.2 These links might help  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/centos/sdk-current

Comment: It works! Thanks @JoeA. Since you posted the solution first, put it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No problem @Vlad happy to help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
sudo yum update 
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-2.2
```

Also this link might help: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/centos/sdk-current

Comment: Before this worked, I had to add the Microsoft signing key as detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos#centos-7-

Answer (score 11):

The following works for .NET Core 3.1 on Amazon Linux 2:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

(or `dotnet-sdk-5.0` for .NET 5)

More detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos#centos-7-

If you're using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and you only need the runtime (not the SDK) then you can just use the [.NET Core / Linux platform](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-net-core-on-linux-platform/).

Comment: If you are doing this in a script, you can add `-y` to the install command so it doesn't prompt you.

Answer (score 5):

Since the Amazon Linux is more akin to open-source Centos than RedHat, you can attempt to follow the yum instructions provided for Centos/Oracle linux.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/centos/sdk-current

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right, it works. But since @Jose A answered first I will accept his. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's what worked for me:**

- Download dotnet sdk manually from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 (pick x64 binaries)
- Extract downloaded tar with `mkdir -p "$HOME/dotnet" && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.1.301-linux-x64.tar.gz -C "$HOME/dotnet"` (you may have to adjust the tar file name)
- Export dotnet root and update path `export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet && export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet`

Afterwards check installation with `dotnet --version`, it should work.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos